# Send PHP mail with AngularJS

Tags: php, email, angularjs

I want to send an email when submitting a form in my AngularJS app.

My email.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
 $receiver = $_REQUEST['to'];
 $subject = "The subject";
 $message .= 'Hello';
 $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
 $header .= "From: mail@mail.com" . "\r\n";

 mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $header);
?>
```

On my form, I have ng-submit="submit()", and this function looks like this:

```
var data = "to=" + $('.user-email').val();
  $scope.url = "/email.php";
  var transform = function(data) {
    return $.param(data);
  }
  $http({
    type: "POST",
    url: $scope.url,
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    transformRequest: transform
  }).success(function(responseData) {
    Console.log('Hurray')
  }).error(function(responseData) {
    console.log('error');
  });
```

However, when I push the submit button, I get the following error: http://cl.ly/image/1k0E2O0Q3c0B

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you do console.log(responseData) instead of 'error' ? It might give more information to work with.

Comment: Does /email.php accept POST requests?

Comment: I've changed .error from only having reponseData to have data, status, headers, config and console.log each of them. The result is this: http://cl.ly/image/2v1I0j070J0G

Comment: @interlude - how do I check if it accepts POST requests?

Comment: This is what I get from the Networks panel: http://cl.ly/image/310t36350c0U

Answer (score 0):

So... The following works:

```
.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "email.php",  
   data: data,  
   success: function() {  
      console.log('yessør');
   }  
 });
```

But if I use the $http.post angular method, it doesn't work - I only get this: http://cl.ly/image/2n0Z0o231l0v  --- a Request Method of 'undefined'. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have a typo? [Angular's $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) expects a `method` key instead of a `type` key.

You also have the shortcut methods (`$http.post`, for instance) that could prevent you from making this kind of error.